# Improve speed of color conversion from sRGB to Lab

Tags: r, performance, raster, color-conversion

I need to convert high-resolution ortho-mosaic photos from sRGB to Lab color space. I've tried using base R function `convertColor()` but I've never accomplished at least one conversion (images over 10 hectares with 5cm pixel resolution, ~50.0000.0000 pixels).

I tried with `patchPlot` package, it has a faster computation. But, considering the size of my images I'm looking a better way to do it.

Is there a package / function / method to improve this computation?

Example test with `convertColor` and `patchPlot::RGB2Lab`:

```
library(raster)
library(patchPlot)
library(microbenchmark)

r <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))

microbenchmark(baseR = convertColor(color = values(r), from = 'sRGB', to = 'Lab'),
               patchPlot = RGB2Lab(values(r)))
## Unit: milliseconds
##       expr        min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
##      baseR 261.702873 282.60345 316.76008 310.31006 327.05536 550.07653   100   b
##  patchPlot   8.335807   9.58279  11.53369  10.11684  11.69073  46.78427   100  a
```

Comment: Does it make sense to split RasterStack into RasterLayers and run RGB2Lab on them?

Comment: @PoGibas the input of `RGB2Lab` is a 3 column matrix, I can't split it

Comment: not even row-wise?

Comment: @PoGibas yes, could be an option to split into groups and apply a parallel processing

Comment: posted my solution with splitting original RGB matrix, waiting for feedback on efficiency

Answer (score 1):

This is far from perfect solution, but we can try to improve it. Thing that you can play around is `nMatrix` (into how many matrices you want to split original RGB matrix).

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(parallel)
library(patchPlot)
library(raster)

# How many matrices we want to have
nMatrix <- 4

# Load raster
r <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package = "raster"))
# Extract value matrix
rValues <- values(r)
n <- nrow(rValues)

# Groups to split rValues into nMatrix parts
foo <- rep(1:nMatrix, each = ceiling(n / nMatrix))
# If group vector exceeds number of rows in matrix then trim it
if (length(foo) > n) {
    foo <- foo[1:n]
}
# Splitted matrices
rValuesSplit <- lapply(split(rValues, foo), matrix, ncol = 3)

microbenchmark(do.call(rbind,mclapply(rValuesSplit, RGB2Lab, mc.cores = 1)))
```

Comment: It's a good approach. But I test this solution comparing `RGB2Lab()` without parallelizing on Windows / OS X machines with R and MRO and I didn't found significative differences